# How to avoid Shopify app opening in a new tab?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

#### THE SITUATION:

I am testing my Shopify app. 
Until few days ago it was working fine. 
The intended behavior was it to be opened embedded in Shopify dashboard.

Recently when I click on the app it opens in a new tab at the following url:

```
https://[STORE-ID].myshopify.com/admin/apps/[APP-NAME]?force_legacy_domain=1
```

Note the `force_legacy_domain` param added to the url.

#### SHOPIFY DOMAIN CHANGE

It seems there have been some changes in the Shopify admin url. 
With the new change it should be opened at the following url:

```
https://admin.shopify.com/store/[STORE-NAME]/apps/[APP-NAME]
```

#### QUESTION:

How can I avoid opening the app in a new tab?

Comment: You should not have to do anything. The fact that Apps now open inside Shopify at a different URL does not determine opening in a new tab or not. Something else is at work in your App. My guess is you should use a network request/response logger for the process, and examine all the calls made from Shopify to your App and go from there to establish where you get a new tab opening. Probably a config you made or forgot?

Comment: Thanks for replying! Good advise, I will check that out. What is baffling to me is that before this behavior wasn't happening. A similar situation as in this Shopify forum post: https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/using-appbridge-3-with-vue/td-p/1935653

Answer (score 1):

I think you answer this one by simply ensuring you are keeping track of the right parameters, and Shopify will not do the new tab. So ensure you have your host and shop parameters throughout the lifecycle of all calls to your App. If you are not setting the host, or handling the admin.shopify.com domain correctly, Shopify is sending you to the legacy handler, and that opens your App in a new tab it seems, reminding you to ensure you are handling all the parameters correctly for both the new and hold Shopify App domains.

Comment: Thanks David, in the next couple of days I will do a overhaul of the workflow, and then come up to approve the answer.

Comment: Hi @FrancescoMussi, I'm also facing a similar issue, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: No sorry @PrashantLuhar. In the end we decided to switch to standalone app, instead of embedded app. [in standalone mode there is not that issue]

Comment: I stand by my answer that the only reason one would have this tab issue it due to misunderstanding how Apps work in browsers. Going standalone to avoid embedded seems like using a sledgehammer to kill a fly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this may be a bug on Shopify's end.

There is a github issue reported here:
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-bridge/issues/160#issuecomment-1425990569

And there is a thread I found on the Shopify developer forums: https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/force-legacy-domain-1-cascading-redirects-using-shopify-app/td-p/1938587